# Asynchronous folder zipping in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, zip

I need to zip multiple folders asynchronously in nodeJS. Is there any way to do an asynchronous zipping in NodeJS.(this needs to be work both on linux and windows computers)

I tried adm-zip library but it seems to be synchronous.

Comment: Did you try jszip?

Comment: no, but I was able to do it using archiver and a promise